# How can I pipe a string that the user input?

Tags: c, shell, unix

I need to pipe a string that's been split into individual arguments. For example,

```
cd foo | cat bar.txt
```

has been parsed and stored into an array

```
char *arr[];
arr = {"cd", "foo", "|", "cat", "bar.txt"}
```

My initial thought is to traverse the array until I see the pipe and store the commands into another array then run it. Is there another way to approach this?

Comment: Look at `sprintf`. Forming your strings is trivial.

Comment: using the original string:  system( "cd foo | cat bar.txt" ); or system( stringName );

Comment: Not allowed to use system()

Comment: You can place a null pointer in place of the `|` string, and another null pointer at the very end, and then the material is (more or less) appropriate for passing to `execvp()`.  Of course `cd` commands require some special handling and don't normally generate any output -- and on the LHS of a pipeline, wouldn't be expected to affect the parent process anyway, so maybe you don't need the special handling in this context.  The `cat` ignores its standard input anyway because it is given a file name to list.

Comment: `cd foo | cat bar.txt` is not a valid piped command. But I think you probably want to do something like `cat bar.txt | grep TEXT`. For that, you need to `fork(2)` for each command, redirect their `STDIN_FILENO` and `STDOUT_FILENO` to each other to a pipe with `dup2(2)` and `pipe(2)`. then run any function from `exec(2)` family for each command.

Answer (score 0):

Yon can use the awk :

str="cd foo | cat bar.txt"

command_first=`echo $str | awk -F "|" '{print $1}'`

command_second=`echo $str | awk -F "|" '{print $2}'`

eval $command_first

eval $command_second